# Url as path parameter in restful api causes bad request

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat5.5

We are developing a restful api using jersey (1.9.1) and tomcat 5.5.
A given resource is identified with a urn and we would like to address a specific instance of that resource. In order to achieve this, we used the following code:

```
@Path("/XXXs")
public interface XXXResource {
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    XXXInfo getXXX(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

The idea is to address this resource using the following url:

http://localhost:8080/restapi/XXXs/http%3A%2F%2Fns.something.com%2FXXX%2F2

The decoded path param value should be:
http://ns.something.com/XXX/2

However, when I make the request using the encoded url I get a bad request message from tomcat. So my questions are:

- Is it correct to use a Urn as a path parameter?
- Why is tomcat considering this request as a bad request?

Just in case, I changed the signature of the method so that the parameter is taken from the query string and it worked fine, but I want the parameter to be part of the path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by adding the following line in catalina.properties:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true